# When is an $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ function bounded everywhere?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have a fairly elementary question regarding Lebesgue spaces that I can't seem to figure out.

As the title suggests, I wish to know what additional condition(s) do we need to impose on a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ so that it is bounded everywhere *(as oppose to almost everywhere)*? Would continuity suffice?

Comment: yes, it is sufficient to get local boundedness.

Comment: Continuity does the trick if you already know that the function is bounded almost everywhere. However, there are continuous functions in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ that are not bounded everywhere. Lipschitz continuity would be a (fairly strong) condition that is sufficient.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Could you perhaps give some examples of continuous functions in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ that isn't bounded everywhere?

Comment: Take a function that is the sum of triangles with height $n$ and base ${1 \over n^3}$.

Comment: The question is not properly posed.  Functions in $L^{p}$ are equivalence classes so you can only ask when  a function in it a.e. equal to a function that is bounded everywhere.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Of course you are right, but given that the OP wants to impose that the equivalence class admits a continuous representative, then we can sweep that under the rug (I mean that representative is unique and we can identify the equivalence class with its continuous representative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Smooth counterexample:** Let me do an example of a smooth function that is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, but not bounded. Pick your favourite smooth function $\varphi$ supported in $[0;1/2]$ and such that $\Vert \varphi \Vert_p=1$. Then we define
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} n^{1/2}\varphi(n^{2p}(x-n)). $$
Then we have
$$ \Vert f \Vert_p \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} n^{1/2}\Vert \varphi(n^{2p}(\cdot - n) \Vert_p
= \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}. $$
Here we used a couple of substitutions
$$ \Vert \varphi(n^{2p}(\cdot - n) \Vert_p =\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \varphi(n^{2p}(x-n)) \vert^p dx \right)^{1/p}
= \left( \int_\mathbb{R} \vert \varphi(n^{2p}y) dy \right)^{1/p}
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} n^{-2p} \vert \varphi(z) dz \right)^{1/p}
= n^{-2} \Vert \varphi \Vert_p = n^{-2}. $$
Thus, $f$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. As the $\varphi(n^{2p}(x-n))$ have disjoint support and $\varphi$ is smooth, so is $f$. Furthermore, again as the $\varphi(n^{2p}(x-n))$ have disjoint support, we get that $\Vert f \Vert_{L^\infty([0;n+1))}= n^{1/2}\Vert \varphi \Vert_\infty$ and hence $\Vert f \Vert_\infty = \infty$.

Of course, this is just a complicated version of the example of copper.hat from the comments. I just wanted to show that continuity or differentiability is not quite enough.

**Lipschitz continuity is enough:** As I wrote in the comments, lipschitz continuity would be sufficient. As $f$ is lipschitz continous, is is enough to show that $\lim_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Assume by contradiction that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ does not hold. Then there exists $C >0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n =\infty$, such that $f(x_n)\geq 2C$ (I assumed wlog that those values are positive and that $\vert x_n - x_m \vert \geq 1$ for $n\neq m$). But our function is lipschitz continuous with, say, lipschitz constant $L>0$. Then we have for $y\in [x_n; x_n +a]$ with $a:=\min \{1/2, C/L \}$
$$ f(y)\geq  f(x_n)- \vert f(y)-f(x_n)\vert \geq 2C - L \vert x_n - y\vert \geq C.$$
Thus, we get
$$\Vert f \Vert_p^p \geq \sum_{n\geq 1} \int_{x_n}^{x_n+a} \vert f(y) \vert^p dy \geq \infty,$$
which contradicts our assumption that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Alternatively, you could assume that $f$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and impose some integrability for $f'$.

As PhoemueX pointed out in the comments below, uniform continuity works as well (would be essentially the same proof).

Comment: Uniform continuity should also be enough.

Comment: @PhoemueX Absolutely. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If I got it right, you take a smooth function $\varphi$  supported in an interval and show that $\|f\|_\infty =\|\varphi\|_\infty =\infty\  ?$ I am unable to find such a "favorite" function $\varphi.$ I have impression that you should slightly modify the definition of $f.$

Comment: @BazyliZuczek Thank you for pointing this out. The scaling is for course off (missed a factor of $n^{1/2}$).